# Seam 2.2.2.Final with maven and Jboss 6

Tags: java, maven, jboss, seam

Hi do anyone have a good artifact for this or any template for it that they would like to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://www.glxn.net/seam-maven-refimpl/doc/tutorial/01-gettingstarted.html

The artifact is for 2.2.1.Final but upgrading to 2.2.2.Final is easy. You can build ears for jboss 4.2.3, 5 and 6.